askubuntu.com should have button "Already have a StackExchange account?"
Clicking on each site on https://stackexchange.com/users/1133105/dan-jacobson?tab=accounts , I find I am already logged into each one, except
https://askubuntu.com/ .

See also
How to link my stackexchange account to askubuntu?
Re: How do I get Askubuntu.com to recognize the fact that i'm already logged-in on Stackexchange? I only use the Chrome browser in its default state. I.e., I represent the average user.
I bet if this were askubuntu.stackexchage.com this wouldn't happen.
Reading Why doesn't Ask Ubuntu let me share my Stack Overflow login? it seems there should be a button on askubuntu.com: "I already have a stackexchange account" that when pushed, tells the user the special steps needed.
Yes, Switching to Ask Ubuntu no longer works tells me that button is very much needed.
